# How do I simply switch view controllers using XIB's in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xib

So I've been looking around, and all I can find is all this super advanced stuff on view controller switching and navigation controllers and a bunch of other crap. All I want to do is make my app so when I touch the "Admissions" button, my iPod displays the content on "Admissions.xib". Some little push or flip animation would be nice. If possible, a GOOD WELL COMMENTED chunk of code would be SO MUCH APPRECIATED.
Thanks,
Ben Scholer

P.S. -- I don't need some fancy thing, just a simple

```
when Admissions button pressed {
// Makes the view controller in Admissions.xib the displayed VC using a short and sweet animation using 
/* this
---------------
---------------
code */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) admissionsButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    AdmissionsViewController *detailViewController = [[AdmissionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Admissions" 
                                                                            bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    //[detailViewController release];  // Do that if you don't ARC.

}
```

Given that `Admissions.xib` is the name of your xib file and `AdmissionsViewController` the name of your view controller class.

Make sure to link the action admissionsButtonPressed: to the related touch up inside event within that view in xib, where the button resides.

What's the issue with that? There are hundrets of tutorials and samples around explaining exactly that. That was about the first stuff that I ever learned from the web when I started coding for iPhones.

Comment: You are right Rob. In that case he simply uses `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead. Or `presentModalViewController:animated:` in the event that he needs to be compatible to earlier versions of iOS. And now that you say that I remember that I had difficulties in the beginning to understand the concept of navigation controllers.

Comment: near `photo:fcPhoto];` it gives me an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'fcPhoto'"

Comment: Yes it does. Apologies. I copied it out of a project where the init method was overwritten. I'll fix it in a minute.

Comment: Yes. I just erased the line with the fcPhoto in it. Should work now. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Its not working... :( I'm not getting any errors, but it just doesn't change views.

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller at all? if not then present the view modally using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: Is a navigation controller that thing a the top? If so, no. And could you provide an example of where your litttle bit of code goes?

Comment: The thing at the top is the navigation bar which comes with a navigation controller. That code sniplet goes to the view controller. Don't forget to add it to the *.h file. (Adding it to the .h may not be required any more but used to be with earlier versions of Xcode. Hoever, it should no do any harm.) And do not forget to actually connect the action with a button event. (Touch Up Inside is best)

Comment: Can you provide an actual like 'preview' of where you put in the .h and .m files?

Comment: In the .h file you put it between `@interface` and `@end` and in the .m file between `@implementation` and `@end`.  Anywhere but not within curly brackets.